# How to load image in actionscript to stage without changing it's size?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, image-processing

I made an application that the user could load an image, then they could edit it. The problem is, when I load an image for the first time, it loaded with it's original pixel size. But when i load another image, the pixel size differ from the original one.

Here is the function code when image loaded to stage :

```
function onFileLoadComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoadComplete);
            loader.loadBytes(loadFileRef.data);

            loadFileRef = null;
        }

        function onDataLoadComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(event.target.content).bitmapData;

            var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.translate(-imageView_mc.x, -imageView_mc.y);
            matrix.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.translate(imageView_mc.x, imageView_mc.y);

            imageView_mc.graphics.clear();
            imageView_mc.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, matrix, false, true); 
            imageView_mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height);
            imageView_mc.graphics.endFill();

            trace ("Image width: " ,imageView_mc.width, ", Image height: " ,imageView_mc.height);


            imageView_mc.width = stage.stageWidth;
            imageView_mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
            (imageView_mc.scaleX < imageView_mc.scaleY) ? imageView_mc.scaleY = imageView_mc.scaleX : imageView_mc.scaleX = imageView_mc.scaleY;
            (imageView_mc.scaleX > imageView_mc.scaleY) ? imageView_mc.scaleY = imageView_mc.scaleX : imageView_mc.scaleX = imageView_mc.scaleY;
            imageView_mc.x = 0.5*(stage.stageWidth-imageView_mc.width);
            imageView_mc.y = 0.5*(stage.stageHeight-imageView_mc.height);
}
```

so, is there something wrong with this code? this code is for loading image to stage, then scale it proportionally to stage size.
Any feedback would be really appreciated.

Comment: where are you assigning the values to scaleX and scaleY used in the matrix initialization?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your scale when loaded new image before applying matrix transform.

```
scaleX = scaleY = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you Serge, but it's not working at all. I put that scaleX = scaleY = 1; in onFileLoadComplete function but nothing happened...

Comment: Hm... maybe you update you question with more code, now it isnt sufficient to understand problem.